# How launch and execute just one coroutine between ViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

Here is my pseudo code.

```
class ViewModel {
    val liveData1: MutableLiveData<String>
        private set

    val liveData2: MutableLiveData<String>
        private set

    fun start() {
        liveData1.value = "render1"
        liveData2.value = "render2"

        /**
        * I want that a Logcat shows a log like below:
        *
        * render1 start
        * render1 end
        * render2 start
        * render2 end
        *
        * but, result was
        *
        * render1 start
        * render2 start
        * render1 end
        * render2 end
        */
    }
}

class Activity { 

    fun onCreate() {
        subscribe()
        viewModel.start()
    }

    fun subscribe() {
        viewModel.livedata1.observe(this, Observer {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                render1() 
            }
        })

        viewModel.livedata2.observe(this, Observer {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                render2() 
            }
        })
    }

    suspend fun render1() {
        Log.d("tag", "render1 start")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("tag", "render1 end")
    }

    suspend fun render2() {
        Log.d("tag", "render2 start")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("tag", "render2 end")
    }

}
```

Everytime I call "launch", It seems that a new coroutine started.

I want to wait updating "livedata2" until end of "livedata1" rendering

Is there any way to update "livedata2" after rendering is completed of "livedata1" ?

(I have to use ViewModel and Livedata also)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not need to use `lifecycleScope.launch` and all will work fine as you intended.

```
  viewModel.livedata1.observe(this, Observer {
            render1()  
        })
```

Also you can launch coroutine on Main thread :

```
  lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            render1() 
       }
```

Comment: If I remove `lifecycleScope.launch`, the compiler complaint that "suspend function should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

Comment: unfortunately, no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
    suspend fun render1() {
        Log.d("tag", "render1 start")
        delay(1000)
        liveData2.postValue("render2")
        Log.d("tag", "render1 end")
    }
```

Comment: according to MVVM architecture, only ViewModel can setValue to the livedata..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're launching coroutines inside observers, they're gonna run concurrently despite they're confined to a single thread (Main). When `delay` is called, the main thread gets suspended instead of blocked, that's why it runs the other task during that time.

To avoid running both render functions concurrently you're gonna have to deal with concurrency, for example using mutual exclusion:

```
class Activity {

    val myMutex = Mutex()

    fun onCreate() {
        subscribe()
        viewModel.start()
    }

    fun subscribe() {
        viewModel.livedata1.observe(this, Observer {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                myMutex.withLock {
                    render1()
                }
            }
        })

        viewModel.livedata2.observe(this, Observer {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                myMutex.withLock {
                    render2()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    suspend fun render1() {
        Log.d("tag", "render1 start")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("tag", "render1 end")
    }

    suspend fun render2() {
        Log.d("tag", "render2 start")
        delay(1000)
        Log.d("tag", "render2 end")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.launch{}` returns a `Job`, so you can save out the reference, then:

```
    suspend fun render2() {
        render1Job.join()
        do rendering
    }
```

See [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html), [Job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html), [join](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/join.html)